# Can pure mathematics alone give proofs in science

Tags: mathematics, laws-of-physics

I reasoned in my last post that because of science's nature of induction and falsifiability, it is impossible to give a theorem in science, unlike in mathematics. It is because even when a scientific deduction is made, that deduction too stems from a scientific fact based on induction and is prone to falsifiability.

Then, can pure mathematics alone give proofs in scinece?

Physicists have long thought that mathematics is the "language of the universe." This implies that while mathematics is capable of describing the universe, it cannot discover the universe.

A good example is Pythagorean "Theorem". Some rationalists believed that $c^2=a^2+b^2$ can be proven without empirical knowledge, but they miss that Pythagorean "Theorem" is deduced from the Euclid's five postulates, some of which (like parallel postulate) are not true in curved spacetime. Pythagorean "Theorem" is in fact a theory, as was falsified in GR.(I'm not underestimating the falsifiability of theory, I'm just objecting its inherit uncertainty)

Comment: "This implies that while mathematics is capable of describing the universe, it cannot discover the universe." Mathematics was used to predict Neptune, radio waves, the Higgs boson, and so on. If that's not 'discovering' the universe then I don't know what is.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/154832/2451

Comment: I don't think this question is well-suited to physics stack exchange - perhaps philosophy stack exchange - though really I'd recommend reading a lot and reaching your own conclusions

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the philosophy of science and epistemology

Comment: Is Pythagorean Theorem not a theorem or have people missed the fact that it is a theorem in Euclidean geometry? GR is using non-Euclidean geometry, and hence the Pythagorean Theorem is inherently inapplicable, but since the theorem never said it is universally applicable and instead only applicable in Euclidean geometry, it remains valid and is still a theorem, not just a theory.

Comment: The answer is "No." and it follows trivially from the definition of science.

Comment: @CuriousOne *the* definition of science?!

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you're asking - there isn't really a question here.

Comment: @innisfree: Of course science has a definition. Did you think your computer was created by a million monkeys punching away on typewriters? There is a system to this madness. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne No of course not. The monkeys didn't have typewriters, so they began toying with wafer furnaces, UV lithography machines and tanks of silane instead. Then they all said, hey, let's go to the stockmarket, which they did in 1970 :) and became Intel.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance: You are absolutely right, the madness wasn't complete until the monkeys got themselves a CEO, an investment bank and went public. Be careful with your tech stocks, it's 1998, again!

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately you will need some postulates (assumptions) about the way nature works before you can prove anything.  The validity of your conclusion then rests in the validity of your assumptions.

For example Einstein postulated that the speed of light is the same in all inertial reference frames when developing special relativity.  An implicit assumption in special relativity was that space-time was flat.

It turns out in nature that the speed of light is the same for all inertial reference frames however space-time is not always flat, only locally flat.  Therefore we know that locally special relativity is accurate since we have performed various experiments confirming the nature of the speed of light.

So a physicist can prove things along the lines of, if assumption A about the world is true, then conclusion B must be true, however they cannot go so far as to say conclusion B is true without doing ane experiment to check that A is true.

Comment: Summarizing your answer with one sentence: "Logic needs a base." This is also seen in mathematics, where axioms/postulates are inherently unprovable.

Comment: @busukxuan - It's the other way around. Axioms are trivially provable. Just invoke the axiom that says X is true, and viola! X is proven.

Comment: @DavidHammen lol, it's like saying "X is true because X is true!"

Answer (score 4):

> Pythagorean "Theorem" is in fact a theory, as was falsified in GR.

General relativity did not falsify the Pythagorean theorem. The Pythagorean theorem is as true now as it was in Euclid's time. Euclid's geometry is a set of theorems that result from a set of axioms regarding the concepts of points, lines, and planes. The Pythagorean theorem follows logically from those axioms. Change every occurrence of "point" to "table", "line" to "chair", and "plane" to "beer mug" and nothing changes. It's still the same mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

You talk about being being prone to falsifiability, but science isn't prone to this being falsifiable is the point. You make predictions about situations where logically multiple things were possible.

Then you ask if X can "give proofs in science" and again, it doesn't matter what X is, because we don't care about proofs in science because the point is to make predictions.

So your questions are backwards from science and even aim away from science.

Now proofs can be useful. They can be useful in the same way as reversible data compression can be useful. You can make a small number of ideas and have a fixed method (with a small description) for generating more ideas from the small number of ideas and then the small number of ideas plus he method serve as a stand in for the large number of ideas that can be generated. So if you want to make lots of predictions it can be efficient t to have a way compress and then decompress them.

And it isn't just convenient. Because in addition to the science versus non science divide there is a decide within science between good science and bad science. And I don't mean the divide between debunked or disproven science and the science that agrees with observations so far. I mean truly good versus bad.

So here is an example of bad science. It will sound silly but bear with me. Imagine you wrote a completely factual and accurate account of every observation so far to date including exactly when they happened and then took a list of random predictions about factual (testable) results including times when they happen. You could sew them together in a giant book, label it a scientific theory and say that it is your theory.

It makes testable predictions for the future, pick one of those future times select a prediction then go compare it to a future observation at that time. It is consistent with all existing results (it was made that way).

But it is bad science. Firstly, no attempt was made to compress the data, it is just pure stamp collecting of facts with no understanding of the universe involved. And secondly since there was no compression used on the past data there is no connection between the reproductions and the predictions.

So this compression business is not needed for science but it is mandatory for good science. So when you try to understand the universe you must compress, so the point of proof, to be generative from more primitive components is essential to (good) science. It is essential to understanding the universe.

Now note that I haven't brought up mathematics yet. Because it isn't relevant. You make your scientific theories and every possible way of thinking has to be on the table to potentially understand the universe because it is outright hubris to exclude something as a tool.

But you can't focus on everything, and individuals can utilize the potential efficiency of building on other's work or on using tools that are widely known by others. This is fine.

But if a mathematician pretends that some axiom somewhere has to be right or true and that their favorite way is the only possible way, then they are wrong and they are not as true a friend of science as they could be.

The route to understanding is not to assume you are correct and be closed to alternatives. In Physics there are no axioms. You make theories that are testable, the good ones give you more out than you put in and also agree with observations and help you learn.

Mathematics can have a role. But we don't want proofs unless they are merely a cog in the machine of getting out more than you put in, part of the compression and decompression process or part of the understanding process.

But any proof if by proof you mean claiming that something has to be a certain way is about that compression and decompression not about the theory selection or judgement.

Physical theories are made because they make predictions about things that could turn out right or wrong. The good ones explain more than you put in them. For instance a good renormalizable theory only needs a finite number of parameters to make predictions, so you can get more out than you put in. The good ones allow you understand by having a good compression on existing knowledge and using the same compression to make the predictions about future situations.

If you goal is to be right, you can stick to the compression and decompression game. But science is more than that. And with science you won't know for sure what will happen, you will only have a theory. And that is not being prone or a failing, it's because it is useful and practical because you can try to predict that which hasn't yet happened but which could go different ways.

Math and Physics are different. If Math is willing to play nice and get along with Physics, they can sit at the table of Science together. If not, Physicists will do their work themselves if they have to because they are driven to understand the universe and are not above doing what needs to be done themselves. Just like experimentalists can and do build new equipment if they need to if the equipment in question is not available commercially.